# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object in Python

Tags: python

I am currently breaking on the subjected break. What is this `TypeError`, and how do I resolve it? What are the necessary amendments required in the code?

```
from urllib.request import urlretrieve

stoxxeu600_url = urllib.request.urlretrieve('https://www.stoxx.com/document/Indices/Current/HistoricalData/hbrbcpe.txt')
vstoxx_url = urllib.request.urlretrieve('https://www.stoxx.com/document/Indices/Current/HistoricalData/h_vstoxx.txt')

data_folder = 'data/' #Save file to local target destination.
stoxxeu600_filepath = data_folder + "stoxxeu600.txt"
vstoxx_filepath = data_folder + "vstoxx.txt"
urlretrieve(stoxxeu600_url,stoxxeu600_filepath)
```

This is the output:

```
File "/home/aryabhatta/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/parse.py", line 938, in splittype
match = _typeprog.match(url)

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: Please include the complete error message.

Answer (score 1):

You can see from the documentation of [`urlretrieve()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve) that the method returns a tuple `(filename, headers)`

In your code, you first call `urlretrieve()` and store it into `stoxxeu600_url`

```
stoxxeu600_url = urllib.request.urlretrieve('https://www.stoxx.com/document/Indices/Current/HistoricalData/hbrbcpe.txt')
```

`stoxxeu600_url` now has `(filename, headers)` returned by `urlretrieve()`

You then call `urlretrieve()` again with `stoxxeu600_url` which is a tuple, and not the str/byte object, that the method expects. Thereby, causing the TypeError.

```
urlretrieve(stoxxeu600_url,stoxxeu600_filepath)
```

To fix it, just set `stoxxeu600_url` to the url and then call the method.

```
from urllib.request import urlretrieve

stoxxeu600_url = 'https://www.stoxx.com/document/Indices/Current/HistoricalData/hbrbcpe.txt'
stoxxeu600_filepath = "stoxxeu600.txt"
urlretrieve(stoxxeu600_url, filename=stoxxeu600_filepath)
```

Comment: @HimanshuDoneria mark as answered if that was what you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

`urlretrieve` wants a string as its first argument. So `stoxxeu600_url` should be a string.

```
from urllib.request import urlretrieve

stoxxeu600_url = 'https://www.stoxx.com/document/Indices/Current/HistoricalData/hbrbcpe.txt'
data_folder = 'data/' #Save file to local target destination.
stoxxeu600_filepath = data_folder + "stoxxeu600.txt"
urlretrieve(stoxxeu600_url, stoxxeu600_filepath)
```